# Converting pdfDocument to byte[] stream - PDFBox Java

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am updating the values of an editable PDF using `PDFBox`. Instead of saving, I want to return stream. I saved it, it works all fine. Now I want to return `byte[]` instead of saving it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String formTemplate = "myFormPdf.pdf";

    try (PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(formTemplate)))
    {
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

        if (acroForm != null)
        {

            PDTextField field = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField( "sampleField" );
            field.setValue("Text Entry");
        }

        pdfDocument.save("updatedPdf.pdf"); // instead of this I need STREAM
    }
}
```

I tried `SerializationUtils.serialize` but it fails to serialize it.

```
Failed to serialize object of type: class org.apache.pdfbox.pdfmodel.PDDcoumemt
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: @CommonMan updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overloaded [`save`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#save(java.io.OutputStream)) method which accepts an `OutputStream` and use `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String formTemplate = "myFormPdf.pdf";

    try (PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(formTemplate)))
    {
        PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

        if (acroForm != null)
        {

           PDTextField field = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField( "sampleField" );
           field.setValue("Text Entry");
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pdfDocument.save(baos);
        byte[] pdfBytes = baos.toByteArray(); // PDF Bytes
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! didn't check the overloaded methods. Working all fine now. thanks